# How to update Service Worker's cached page with new React/Redux page?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm creating a website (PWA) which is fully usable offline. For demonstration purpose let's say, I'm developing [keep.google.com](http://keep.google.com/).

When I go offline and I make some changes to the Redux state (add a new note) I want that new note to be there after page reload.

The problem is, that Service Worker returns the cached original response (how it was generated at the server) which doesn't contain the newly added note.

**Question**: How can I update the Service Worker with the new Redux state, so it will show the newly added note after page reload when I'm offline?

**Devstack**: Webpack, React, Redux.
I'm using [`sw-precache-webpack-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sw-precache-webpack-plugin) for generating Service Worker.

**Condition**: I want to keep using server rendering with content because of SEO, so I'm not returning just [app shell](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/app-shell) from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to have **fully offline** and **server render**, here is my suggestion:

- **Step 1**: you should store all you notes at client side using `localStorage` or something similar.
- **Step 2**: whenever you create a new note, you should also add them in to your `localStorage`.
- **Step 3**: when your app renders, you read all the notes from `localStorage` and re-render to the UI. And then send an additional request to server to get your newly added notes (maybe from devices). Display them to the UI and save all these new notes to `localStorage`.

This way, on your first visit, you get benefit from Server Side Rendering. Then your page will be cached (until there is a new app version).

On repeat visits, Service Worker returns your page from the first visit (with old notes), but your app logic then check for data in `localStorage` and render them in order to make the page up to date.

There will be a delay time to sync notes from other device because we have to send one additional request. But that's worth it, I think.